# Здравствуйте! Вопрос по поводу MVC на PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Достаточно много времени использую свой небольшой MVC-фреймворк написанный на PHP, дело в том что я не понимаю нарушаю-ли я MVC-подход писав модели не как в популярных фреймворках типа yii или laravel. Контроллера мои могут использовать либо стоковую модель со всеми методами для работы с БД (Родительскую для остальных моделей), либо использовать отдельно написанную для этого контроллера модель (если работа уже более специфичная, например работа с файлами, отправка писем на почтовые адреса, создание паролей). Вот именно это меня беспокоит - для контроллеров я частенько пишу собственные модели с определенными методами, например для регистрации создаю контроллер RegisterController, модель - RegisterModel (с генерациями паролей, использованием PHPMailer). Люди смотрю такого подхода не все придерживаются тк говорят что тем самым осуществляется "привязка" контроллера к модели. Я примерно понимаю о чем они мне хотят сказать, но ведь самым что я создаю модели со специфическим функционалом для определенных контроллеров не должно нарушать MVC-подход? В моей системе контроллера отдельно, модели тоже. Захочет контроллер - будет использовать модель, не захочет - будет работать только с представлением. Правильно-ли я поступаю когда пишу код именно так со стороны MVC?

Comment: У mvc нет строгой реализации, что надо делать именно так а не иначе. Основная идея в том, что к одной модели может обращаться много контроллеров, а у них может быть еще больше вьюх. Но нет ничего страшного в том, чтобы унести достаточно специфическую логику в отдельную  модель, особенно, если это сделает структуру проекта в целом более понятной. Но просто ко всему надо относится без фанатизма и не делать vmc ради mvc. Главное, чтобы код работал, был понятен и мог быть гибко и безболезненно масштабирован.

Comment: Вот по поводу чтобы код работал и был понятен тут вообще без проблем... Но вот соблюдения основной идеи нету. Есть модель родительская с большим количеством методов для работы с бд, а есть специфические модели для определенных контроллеров которым родительской модели не хватает.

Comment: По сути, каждый сам определяет рамки MVC.. Если говорить конкретно о себе - в моделях только связанное с базой выношу, для остального создаю сервисы, аля, то что выше вы упоминали, отправка почты, генераторы и т.п..